# What factors must be taken into account for the maintenance of the immunogenicity of ovalbumin antigen?

Tags: immunology, vaccination

What factors must be taken into account for the maintenance of the immunogenicity of ovalbumin antigen?

If the ovalbumin is aggregated, could we inject it for induction of immune reponse?

Comment: The preparation of a soluble antigen for injection often includes treatment with an adjuvant which usually creates aggregates of some sort. It is my understanding that particulate antigenic material is preferable because it elicits a better immune response.

Comment: Do u know the size of antigens which aggregated by the effect of adjuvant?  If the aggregates' size are around 150 um, do they can activate the immune response? I've read a review article  that suggested that the size of particle (Drug delivery system) should be 1 um for the advantage of to be engulf by phagocytes. It seem like, the antigen aggregate more than 1 um, can not be engulf by the phagocytes ?

Answer (score 2):

Ovalbumin is frequently used in immunology to induce an immune response (see some publications about mice and ovalbumin [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%28ovalbumin%5BTitle%5D%29%20AND%20mice%5BTitle%5D).
You usually inject it together with an adjuvans to enhance the reaction. The factors that must be taken into account for its maintainance are the same as for the other antigens, so you should boost this "vaccination" from time to time.